# Upload multiple files to remote server with PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm about uploading file to remote server using fsockopen() without using context. I'm able to post values but I can't get a way to upload files, like how the header should be arranged, how Content-Length is calculated.... Can anybody give me an example or an explanation of it?

Comment: HTTP protocol specifications: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody give me an example or an explanation of it?

***Hell*** no!  Manually managing HTTP connections is a royal pain in the butt.  Smarter people than you and I have worked hard to create libraries for us to use.  Use one!

I'm partial to [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html), a mostly stand-alone component in the Zend Framework.  It has instructions right there in the documentation on how to perform a file upload.

Some people like [PEAR's HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2).  While it doesn't have an explicit example on how to do uploads [in the manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php), it can do so via the [`addUpload`](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/latest/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2.html#methodaddUpload) method.

If you want something a bit more low-level, you can use the [almost-always-there curl extension](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), which has [a variety of file upload options and examples in the manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

But please, please don't write your own at the socket level.  It is *entirely* unnecessary and will only lead to pain and horrors.